# find if an element has empty elements inside jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to find if a `div` element that is populated with a lot of tables from an system i don't have control over is empty. And by empty I mean if the tables inside the div don't any content inside.

This is the stripped down markup that the system generates:

```
<div class="shadowBox">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In some situations the second (most inner) table has content inside, and in some situations it doesn't. I want to hide the div if there is no content inside the second table. I can achieve this by going trough the structure and checking for the html of the td:

```
$.trim($(".shadowBox table tbody tr td table tbody tr td").html())==""
```

Is there any simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$.trim($(".shadowBox").text())===""
```

which:

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, including their descendants.

If that is empty, hide it

```
if($.trim($(".shadowBox").text())===""){
     $(".shadowBox").hide();
}
```

Comment: Didn't know that the text() method returned combined text from the descendants

Answer (score 3):

This solution will get all the divs that have the shadowBox class that don't have content.

here is the code:

```
$(".shadowBox").filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "";
}).hide();
```

Test it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6mbts/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.trim($(".shadowBox table table").text())==""
```

That should do it. .text() will grab all text (none html) in your selected element(s).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

It will return the combined text content of every descendant of your div

```
if($(".shadowBox").text() == '')
    console.log('Empty');
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the jquery `:empty` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)) selector

```
$("shadowBox table tbody tr td table tbody tr td:empty")
```

Comment: Empty doesn't work, i have to trim the td's html to see if its emtpy